# Хочу сделать что-то вроде импровизированного словарика с английскими словами. Подскажите куда копать

Tags: python, c++, c, qt

Хочу сделать вот что:
Читаю я статью на английском и тут внезапно - новое слово, я его выделил, нажал правую кнопку мыши а там: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как проще всего будет такое сделать? К языку не сильно привязан, чем проще делается тем лучше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается в несколько подходов. Для начала для браузере нужно написать расширение, что бы добавить свой пункт меню. Так как на картинке хром, то для него это [chrome extention](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/). И даже есть микропример, как сделать свой пункт меню - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468429/add-contextmenu-items-to-a-chrome-extensions-browser-action-button

Когда меню заработает, то используя возможность javascript, надо научится брать текущее выделенное слово, например, вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164474/chrome-extension-get-selected-text

И осталось последнее - а где хранить найденные слова.

Можно отправлять на внешний сервер - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107774/how-do-i-send-an-http-get-request-from-a-chrome-extension - а сам сервер пишите на чем угодно, хоть на питоне, хоть на плюсах, хоть на баше (есть и такие специалисты).

А можно хранить в "локальном хранилище браузера" - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/ - но это будет привязано к конкретному браузеру.

В целом, тут все зависит от Вас и Ваших желаний.

Comment: и тут снова друг минусатор. Просто заходит и все, что видит, минусует... интересно

Comment: А из ОС сделать это можно? Ну выделенное слово брать?Т.е чтобы не только в браузере работало, но и в системе. Книгу я скачал в pdf и читаю ее, выделил и сделал все выше проделанное

Comment: а давайте чуточку поменяем Вашу идею, Раз Вы выделяете слово, то нажать ctrl+c не сложно. А на это можно повесить проверку (по факту изменения буфера обмена) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/how-do-i-monitor-clipboard-changes-in-c - и Ваша программа просто будет следить. Если слово уже есть в словаре или слишком длинное - молчим. Если подходящее - делам всплывашку в трее